# How to resolve a collision between a rotating rectangle and an edge

Tags: rotation, 2d, physics, collision, resolution

I'm trying to work out the proper way to resolve collisions between a rectangle and an edge,
At the moment I'm interested in resolving a collision of one of the rectangle's points with an edge,
and hoping collisions between the rectangle's side and an edge will follow naturally.
I've had problems finding information on how a collision like that works exactly though.

I would like to know how to calculate the rotational velocity, I assume it depends on the velocity of the centre of mass of the rectangle, the velocity of the point that's colliding, and the relation of the normal vector of the edge and the velocity vector, to work out what fraction of the velocity(velocities?, do you factor in both the point's velocity and the COM's velocity?) should be turned into rotational velocity.

I also assume depending on the angle of impact, force may also be applied to the COM's velocity, I can kind of intuit how this should work, but can't seem to fit it all together,
again,
How to work out what portion of the velocity(ies) should be applied to pushing the rectangle away from the edge it collided with, and how to work out the direction.

I'm also guessing that friction at the moment of impact might have a sizable effect on the distribution of force, any hints on that would also be appreciated.

I made a little illustration of the effect I'm going after though I'm not sure if it's entirely accurate to what the actual collision response would be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGRot.png)

Here's my code, though it's moot as I'm confused about the actual physics.

```
 void caclulateRotationSpeedAndDirection(int id, sf::Vector2f lineNormal)
    {
//update the centre of mass position
        centre = { (points[0].x + points[2].x) * 0.5f,  (points[0].y + points[2].y) * 0.5f };


        sf::Vector2f centrePoint = points[id] - centre;
        sf::Vector2f pointVec = points[id] - pointsPrev[id];
        float direction;
        // Determine direction of rotation by checking if the angle between the line normal and the vector between the centre and collision point is clockwise or anti-clockwise
        if (angleDirection(lineNormal, centre - points[id])) direction = -1;
        else direction = 1;

        //Calculate how much force to apply to the velocity vector
        float pushFraction = (90-GetAngleBetweenVectors(vel, centrePoint));
        if (pushFraction < 0) pushFraction = -pushFraction;
   
    //angle variable determines speed of rotation, positive or negative -> clockwise or anti-clockwise

        angle = -direction  * calculateRotationalVelocity(id,lineNormal) * getMagnitude(pointVec);
//force applied to COM velocity
        sf::Vector2f v = normalise(-centrePoint * pushFraction * 0.011f) * getMagnitude(vel);
        vel += v;
        

    }

    float calculateRotationalVelocity(int id, const sf::Vector2f& lineNormal) {
        // Calculate the distance between the center of mass and the collision point
        sf::Vector2f collisionPoint = points[id];
        sf::Vector2f distance = collisionPoint - centre;

        // Calculate the perpendicular distance from the collision point to the line
        float perpendicularDistance = std::abs(distance.x * lineNormal.x + distance.y * lineNormal.y);
        cout << "perpendicular distance: " << perpendicularDistance << endl;
        // Calculate the rotational velocity using the perpendicular distance and the distance from the center of mass
        float rotationalVelocity = perpendicularDistance / getMagnitude(distance);

        return rotationalVelocity;
    }
```